# Are sqlite databases more efficient (in terms of RAM usage) than the dplyr library in R?

Tags: r, database

I have to perform a left join on two large datasets. My understanding of dplyr is that it duplicates (temporarily) the two datasets in memory (or something similar which generates a large temporary increase in RAM usage) in order to perform the left join.

Due to the size of the two datasets and the RAM on my machine (8GB) I cannot afford to perform this join using dplyr since it just freezes.

I was wondering whether performing the join in a sqlite database and then import the resulting table in R would solve the problem..